# Gulp Angular build templateCache issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp

My `build.js` is using `ngHtml2js` to convert partials in directives into js files.

```
gulp.task('partials', function () {
  return gulp.src('src/{components,app}/**/*.html')
    .pipe($.ngHtml2js({
      moduleName: 'testApp'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp'))
    .pipe($.size());
});
```

Where, my directives are situated in components folder in components->directives.

The issue is that when I try to deploy the dist folder, the static partial calls from the routes JS files gets fired, and I get a 404.

```
angular.module(ModuleName)
        .directive('collapseWindow', ['$parse', function (parse) {

            return {
                templateUrl:'/components/directives/collapse.html',
                transclude:true,
                restrict: 'A'
```

In my understanding, the ngHtml2js converts the partials into module.run blocks as

```
module.run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put('components/directives/collapse.html',
    '<div class="collapsible">\n' ...
```

But then, why am I getting a 404 error such as

```
 GET http://localhost:3000/components/directives/collapse.html 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 4):

Solved it. The reason was templateUrl were given absolute paths (with '/' at beginning), but templateCache uses relative paths. Thus removing the '/' from templateUrls solved the issue

Comment: how did you remove the / from the beginning?

Comment: just removed the '/' from beginning of the templateUrl settings, ie by setting : `templateUrl:'components/directives/collapse.html'`, without the starting /

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the template module as a dependency in your Angular application module.
Also ensure that your template cache js file has been loaded in browser before your application code.

Comment: sorry couldn't get you. how to add template module as a dependency? Also the code works normally in gulp serve, but only breaks in gulp serve:dist

Answer (score 0):

I added this config for main app. It overwrites template mapping for ngnewroute

```
.config (function ($componentLoaderProvider) {
  $componentLoaderProvider.setTemplateMapping(function (name) {
    return 'components/' + name + '/' + name + '.html';
  });
})
```